# Search functionality not working using ID field input

Tags: cakephp

I am using the search plugin on https://github.com/cakedc/search. I am trying to search for records using the ID field only, that is if i type in 1 on my form input it must show a record with user ID 1. The challenge that i am having now is when i specify that the input should be the id field, the input field for the search functionality disappears on my index view, strange thing is when i specify a different field name the input field shows.

**Below is my code for my Model**

```
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

public $filterArgs = array(
'id' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' => 'ItSupportRequest.id'),
);

public function findByTags($data = array()) {
$this->Tagged->Behaviors->attach('Containable', array('autoFields' => false));
$this->Tagged->Behaviors->attach('Search.Searchable');
$query = $this->Tagged->getQuery('all', array(
'conditions' => array('Tag.name'  => $data['tags']),
'fields' => array('foreign_key'),
'contain' => array('Tag')
));
return $query;
}

public function orConditions($data = array()) {
$filter = $data['filter'];
$cond = array(
'OR' => array(
$this->alias . '.id LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
));
return $cond;
```

}

**and here is my controller code.**

```
public $components = array('Search.Prg');

public $presetVars = true; // using the model configuration

public function find() {
$this->Prg->commonProcess();
$this->paginate['conditions'] = $this->ItSupportRequest->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
$this->set('articles', $this->paginate());
}
```

**and in my index.ctp file i have this code.**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('ItSupportRequest', array(
'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'find'), $this->params['pass'])
));
echo $this->Form->label('Query ID:') . "<br/>";        
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('div' => false, 'label' => false));

echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search'), array('div' => false));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see any "id" - only "name"

Answer (score 0):

You should not call it id as id will be hidden (because cake assumes this is a primary key here).

Either name it something else or manually overwrite this behavior using

```
$this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'text'));
```

But I would go with sth like "search" and

```
$this->Form->input('search', array('placeholder' => 'ID to look for'));
```

and

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    'search' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' => 'ItSupportRequest.id'),
);
```

Comment: what do you mean with wrong? also, why using like with IDs? ids are values - so there is no point in using like here.

Comment: If you use "search" as form field, you need to make your key in filterArgs "seach" as well.

Comment: Wrong i mean its showing all the records in the table. Not sure what i am missing though. model code below

    public $displayField = 'search';
    public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');
    public $filterArgs = array('search' => array('field' => 'ItSupportRequest.id'),